# Handle URL redirect in Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-webview

In my app, I load a webview (login form) which redirects me to the actual login form which I then display in the same webview. This webview is called from my onCreateView as,

```
new FetchLoginFormTask().execute();
```

However, I am intermittently noticing, android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, which makes me think that webView.loadUrl() method is causing this. I am unable to reproduce this all the time so, I created an Asynctask within onPostExecute() but I noticed in the logcat that I can't call webview from within another asynctask. What are my options in ensuring that the login form loads without any ANRs or what best practices am I missing?

```
private class FetchLoginFormTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Response> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Response doInBackground(String... params) {

        int paramLen = params.length;
        Response result = MyOAuth.fetchLoginForm();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response result) {

        if (result != null) {
            //in case of redirect
            if (result.getCode() == 302) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Response was redirect: " + result.getCode());
                //TODO: isn't this a network operation on main UI thread?
                webView.loadUrl(result.getHeader("Location"));
            } else {
                String html = result.getBody();
                webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            }
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: loadUrl is asynchronous so it can be called from the main thread without blocking it. Are you sure getCode() and getBody() do not perform any network operation?

Comment: @NathanZ yes, both getCode() and getBody() are performing operations on the retrieved result so, no network communication. Also, Response is: org.scribe.model.Response